# How to open such visual tool in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I suddenly got such view, but could not find anymore.
How to get this view again?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the view hierarchy debugger. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html

Towards the bottom of the window in the pane with the debugging options:

[image]